# The moment of inertia: limits for angles.

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

I have this task: Calculate the moment of inertia of a homogeneous body
$G$, bounded by the surface $\{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2=a^3z,\, a>0\}$ [(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0I9X.png) relative to the axis of the application $OZ$. In the solution, we move to spherical coordinates, in which we set the following boundaries for the new body: $\Omega:\{0\leq \varphi \leq 2\pi, 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2, 0 \leq \rho \leq a\sqrt[3]{\cos \theta}\}$ [(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cuB4.png). Why do we have such limits for phi and theta?

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions.

Comment: Substitute spherical coordinates into $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2=a^3z$. What did you get? What is on the left-hand side?? Is that factor always positive???